# How can I make a login system with a dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, authentication

I want to login system with dictionary.This code is working but if I write a different username on the login screen, the program gives an error.

```
database={'name': '1234', 'name2': '5678', 'name3': '9012'}

def log():
    name = input('Enter username: ')
    ask = input('Enter pin: ')
    if ask in database[name]:
        print ('Welcome', name)
    else:
        print ('Invalid code')
log()
```

Comment: [Edit] your post and add the full error traceback. It will help us help you.

Comment: You need to use a `try/catch` block

Comment: `database[name]` is a `KeyError` if `name not in database`. Maybe use `database.get` instead.

Comment: Show us the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are querying `database[name]` without first checking that `name` is in `database`. Instead do:

```
database={'name': '1234', 'name2': '5678', 'name3': '9012'}

def log():
    name = input('Enter username: ')
    ask = input('Enter pin: ')
    if name in database:
        if ask == database[name]: # changed this to an 'equals' rather than 'in'
            print ('Welcome', name)
        else:
            print ('Pin wrong!')
    else:
        print ('Username does not exist.')

log()
```

Answer (score -1):

First you have to check if the username actually exists because otherwise you are getting an error because your trying to access an entry in the dict that does not exist.